# How can I unit test my API client file download function properly?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, axios

I am utilizing a custom API client wrapper around Axios in my React application and I'm at quite a loss as to how to test the function utilized to download files properly.  I have no issues testing both the `get` and `post` methods, but the `postForFile` has really got me stumped.

**apiClient.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const getData = response => response.data;

export default class apiClient {
  constructor(baseURL) {
    this.axios = axios.create({ baseURL });
  }

  get = (url, ...args) => this.axios.get(url, ...args).then(getData);

  post = (url, data) => this.axios.post(url, data).then(getData);

  postForFile = (url, data, mimeType, fileName) =>
    this.axios.post(url, data, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then(response => {
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      mimeType = mimeType || 'application/octet-stream';

      if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        // IE10
        navigator.msSaveBlob(
          new Blob([response.data], {
            type: mimeType
          }),
          fileName
        );
      } else if (URL && 'download' in a) {
        // html5 A[download]
        a.href = URL.createObjectURL(
          new Blob([response.data], {
            type: mimeType
          })
        );
        a.setAttribute('download', fileName);
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
      } else {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals
        location.href = `data:application/octet-stream,${encodeURIComponent(response.data)}`;
      }
    });
}
```

**apiClient.test.js**

```
import ApiClient from '../apiClient';

describe('ApiClient', () => {
  const apiClient = new ApiClient('http://localhost:8080');

  it('calls GET mocked axios via ApiClient and returns data', () => {
    apiClient.get('common/AppData').then(result => {
      expect(result).toEqual('get completed');
    });
  });

  it('calls POST mocked axios via ApiClient and returns data', () => {
    apiClient.post('common/AppData', { test: true }).then(result => {
      expect(result).toEqual('post completed');
    });
  });

  it('calls POST (for file) mocked axios via ApiClient and returns data', () => {
    apiClient.postForFile('common/FileData', { test: true }, 'applicaton/pdf', 'TestFile.pdf').then(result => {
      // ?
    });
  })
});
```

And finally, my mock file:

**axios.js**

```
export default {
  create: jest.fn(() => ({
    get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: 'get completed' })),
    post: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: 'post completed' }))
  }))
};
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure you can check that programmatically; the only thing that comes to mind is to listen for errors that occur, and assume it worked if none do.

Comment: Sort of my thought as well...a bit of a bummer, though I was hoping there was at least some way to test it.

Comment: The function doesn't return anything and has no effect on the page. I don't see how you can directly determine if it was successful; all you can do is infer it.